# Why is it possible to make machines and circuits that are so useful, when conservation of energy does not favor it?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

Because of conservation of energy, it's impossible to make energy out of nothing. Thus, we are just shuffling energy around. I'm learning about circuits right now, and I know about simple machines. I understand how they work, but I can't understand the broad-scale reasons for why these machines are SO useful. Why is it that we can accomplish SO much just by moving energy around and releasing it at the right time and in the right form? (Learning about capacitors so I used this wording, but I think its true for all machines). I'm looking for some kind of philosophical backbone, but the answer is definitely rooted in the physics, so I'm asking it here.

Comment: Aren't you answering your question by saying "we can accomplish SO much just by moving energy around and releasing it at the right time and in the right form?" If we want to lift something, we can convert internal energy of fuel into mechanical energy. If we want light, we can convert electrical energy into electromagnetic energy (and usually at the same time waste a lot of heat energy). What deeper meaning are you trying to uncover?

Comment: Utility is a subjective concept, it is not good for a mosquito to be killed while trying to take some blood from us...

Comment: The "philosophical idea" that I can't grasp is that we are able to create things like computers or rockets that let us accomplish things that were never before possible, so it kinda feels like there should be a tradeoff in creating these things. Why is it possible to continually advance SO much? It feels like computers accomplish much more than what it took to make them (the brainpower, making all the components, and actually running them). Where is this thinking wrong?

Comment: @vler Now that I see your comment it is apparent to me your question has nothing to do with physics. Asking what the tradeoffs are in the advancement of technology has nothing to do with "conservation of energy".

Comment: Well I was thinking that the energy that goes into producing the device at all stages must be used somewhere. It appears that computers do a lot more for us than the sum of their parts. Thus, I think, that value that they produce must come from somewhere. I then thought it might come from the mental energy used to come up with the inventions. I know that in some sense this sounds completely unscientific, but I was hoping there might be some sort of scientific clarification for these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to say that conservation of energy does not favor machines and circuits that are useful.  ALL machines and circuits are less than 100% efficient, so all machines turn some of their input energy into work and some of their input energy into heat (which usually represents "lost" work).  In the real world this is unavoidable.

The type of work that you want to obtain from a given input energy depends on what you need.  To type this message on Physics StackExchange, I need the local power plant to boil water, use the resulting steam to turn a turbo-generator, and use that turbo-generator to generate enough electricity to allow me to use my computer.  Admittedly, there are energy losses in each energy conversion step, and in the transmission of electrical power to my house, but it is currently not possible to convert the fuel to the electrical generation facility (e.g., natural gas) directly into electricity.

Comment: The "philosophical idea" that I can't grasp is that we are able to create things like computers or rockets that let us accomplish things that were never before possible, so it kinda feels like there should be a tradeoff in creating these things. Why is it possible to continually advance SO much? Would your answer be that each of these machines actually takes more energy than it produces, and that is the tradeoff? It feels like computers accomplish much more than what it took to make them (the brainpower, making all the components, and actually running them). Where is this thinking wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your comparison between philosophy and science.  We are only limited by our imagination, and there is no "conservation of ideas" ... ideas can literally be created out of nothing, without limit.

Comment: My general confusion is with the massive productivity we get from modern machines. I understand that with a pulley, we pull something twice as far away with half the force, and achieve a balance where we can lift heavier things than with bare hands. It feels, intuitively, that something is conserved. On the other hand, computers do not feel this way, it feels as if once computers were invented, they give us so much more than the sum of the parts.

Comment: Computers are no more intelligent than your car.  Their lowest level operations are completely "mechanical" in nature, in that instructions are merely executed as a series of on and off switches.  The real productivity arises from the speed at which those switches can be turned on and off, and in the creativity of the programmers in telling those switches what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it possible to make machines and circuits that are so useful,
>   when conservation of energy does not favor it?

Machines make it possible to accomplish tasks using the same amount of energy than without machines. A pulley system makes it possible to lift a weight with a tenth of the force needed without the pulley system. You just need to apply the force for a distance 10 times greater than without the pulley system in order to satisfy the law of conservation of energy (Work equal force time distance).

It's called mechanical advantage.

Hope this helps.